# On-prem kubernetes management

Tags: kubernetes

I am currently using ubuntu machines for creating a kubernetes cluster.

All machines are on-prem.

but adding / upgrating machines, require lot of maintanence like installing ubuntu, adding needed packages, open-ssh, then adding kubernetes and adding to cluster.

Is there a better way to install and add machines to kubernetes cluster.

Comment: You can try with Rancher v2, quite simple setup, It has GUI management and many plugins/apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many products and projects available for this. You'll just have to try some and see which you like. I couldn't list them all if I tried but a few I'm pretty sure are compatible with Ubuntu (in no particular order):

- kubespray
- Rancher (and RKE with it)
- Microk8s (uses Snaps)
- Charmed Kubernetes